# Alexa : How to login with my keystore on Android OS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, alexa-skills-kit

Any one has experience with Alexa application login?

I have faced with trouble with login with Alexa.
When I downloaded SDK and launch it, then it works fine.
But I tried with my keystore and API key, just not working.

I registered my keystore MD5 in my account, 
but when I click consent button on the web browser during login,
"This webpage is not available" displayed.

Please help.

Comment: Show the code you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

I found my previous problem. 
That was in AndroidManifest information was wrong.
But still have problem with login.

I used below information to login, but authentication error coming.

```
PRODUCT_ID = "DA_AVS_TEST_ID";
PRODUCT_DSN = "1234";
CODE_CHALLENGE = "5cd6cb5512be8c93d750b7841b5ae51ef32381c0a34511ce42d442c7c313ee72";



final Bundle options = new Bundle();
        String scope_data = "{\"alexa:all\":{\"productID\":\"" + PRODUCT_ID +
                            "\", \"productInstanceAttributes\":{\"deviceSerialNumber\":\"" +
                            PRODUCT_DSN + "\"}}}";
        options.putString(AuthzConstants.BUNDLE_KEY.SCOPE_DATA.val, scope_data);

        options.putBoolean(AuthzConstants.BUNDLE_KEY.GET_AUTH_CODE.val, true);
        options.putString(AuthzConstants.BUNDLE_KEY.CODE_CHALLENGE.val, CODE_CHALLENGE);
        options.putString(AuthzConstants.BUNDLE_KEY.CODE_CHALLENGE_METHOD.val, "S256");

        mAuthManager.authorize(APP_SCOPES, options, new AuthListener());
        mLoginButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.login_with_amazon);
        mLoginButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mAuthManager.authorize(APP_SCOPES, options, new AuthListener());
            }
        });

09-01 17:09:51.765: E/com.test.amazon.hyunchoh.SampleLoginWithAmazonActivity(9284): AuthError during authorization
09-01 17:09:51.765: E/com.test.amazon.hyunchoh.SampleLoginWithAmazonActivity(9284): AuthError cat= INTERNAL type=ERROR_SERVER_REPSONSE - com.amazon.identity.auth.device.AuthError: Error=invalid_scope_data error_description=lwa-invalid-parameter-bad-scope-data
09-01 17:09:51.765: E/com.test.amazon.hyunchoh.SampleLoginWithAmazonActivity(9284):     at com.amazon.identity.auth.device.authorization.AuthorizationResponseParser.constructErrorBundle(AuthorizationResponseParser.java:137)
09-01 17:09:51.765: E/com.test.amazon.hyunchoh.SampleLoginWithAmazonActivity(9284):     at com.amazon.identity.auth.device.authorization.AuthorizationResponseParser.extractResultsBundle(AuthorizationResponseParser.java:83)
09-01 17:09:51.765: E/com.test.amazon.hyunchoh.SampleLoginWithAmazonActivity(9284):     at com.amazon.identity.auth.device.authorization.AuthorizationActivity.onCreate(AuthorizationActivity.java:41)
09-01 17:09:51.765: E/com.test.amazon.hyunchoh.SampleLoginWithAmazonActivity(9284):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5428)
09-01 17:09:51.765: E/com.test.amazon.hyunchoh.SampleLoginWithAmazonActivity(9284):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
09-01 17:09:51.765: E/com.test.amazon.hyunchoh.SampleLoginWithAmazonActivity(9284):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2281)
09-01 17:09:51.765: E/com.test.amazon.hyunchoh.SampleLoginWithAmazonActivity(9284):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2375)
09-01 17:09:51.765: E/com.test.amazon.hyunchoh.SampleLoginWithAmazonActivity(9284):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:164)
09-01 17:09:51.765: E/com.test.amazon.hyunchoh.SampleLoginWithAmazonActivity(9284):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1268)
09-01 17:09:51.765: E/com.test.amazon.hyunchoh.SampleLoginWithAmazonActivity(9284):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
09-01 17:09:51.765: E/com.test.amazon.hyunchoh.SampleLoginWithAmazonActivity(9284):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
09-01 17:09:51.765: E/com.test.amazon.hyunchoh.SampleLoginWithAmazonActivity(9284):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5377)
09-01 17:09:51.765: E/com.test.amazon.hyunchoh.SampleLoginWithAmazonActivity(9284):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-01 17:09:51.765: E/com.test.amazon.hyunchoh.SampleLoginWithAmazonActivity(9284):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-01 17:09:51.765: E/com.test.amazon.hyunchoh.SampleLoginWithAmazonActivity(9284):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
09-01 17:09:51.765: E/com.test.amazon.hyunchoh.SampleLoginWithAmazonActivity(9284):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
09-01 17:09:51.765: E/com.test.amazon.hyunchoh.SampleLoginWithAmazonActivity(9284):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```